# How to display error message in password protected form using ajax jQuery?

Tags: custom-post-types

In a custom post type that is protected, I'm password protecting the post via WordPress' native functionality. Looking for a native solution to display error message in password protected form using ajax jQuery that could not reload the page if it has an error like invalid password.